# Sub-domains of the computable numbers

Tags: number-theory

Does there exist a minimal domain whose field of quotients is the field of computable numbers ?

Comment: I suspect not, since there is no such a minimal domain even for $\Bbb Q(i)$:  $\{a + bi\mid a\in\Bbb Z,b\in p\Bbb Z\}$ has quotient field $\Bbb Q(i)$ for any $p$, but if you want to be contained inside of each of these, you'd better be $\Bbb Z$ (which, as you know, has fraction field $\Bbb Q$).